# How to show messages in a chat like manner

Tags: reactjs, concatenation

I got an array of chat messages from an API call & I mapped it to a component (shown in code below). In that component I rendered the messages according to a condition set. But .map method is just replacing the previous message with a new one. I want to .concat() these messages & show them one by one like in a chat.

ChatBox Component:

```
this.state = {
messages: [] }

getNewMessages() {
//api called & got response
this.setState({
messages: parsedResponse });
}

render() {
  return(<>
{messages.map(messages => (
<NewMessages data={messages} />))}</>)
}
```

NewMessages Component: -

```
`this.state = { message: this.props.data.message }`

`return(<p>{message}</p>)`
```

How can I concat this array so that I can get all the messages instead of only last one.

Comment: The usage of URGENT is not cool/kind, Kindly learn how to ask questions the right way

Comment: kindly post complete components. As far as I see you are mapping array of messages which is not the one in the state.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @kikuyu  sorry i am not aware of the stackoverflow Etiquettes. Will remember this in future.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't knew this. Will keep in mind in future.

Answer (score 1):

Spread operator can help you with it.

```
getNewMessages() {
    //api called & got response
    this.setState({
        messages: [...this.state.messages, ...parsedResponse]
    });
}
```

And just render the message itself.

```
render() {
    return(
        <>
              {this.state.messages.map(messages => (<p>{message}</p>))}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: @Anuja Np. If you can approve my answer it would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    return messages.forEach(m => `<div>${m}</div>`);
}
```